# How do you stop Flash Builder 4 Actionscript project launching Flash IDE?

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I am trying to create an Actionscript project in Flash Builder 4. However when I debug or run it always runs in the Flash IDE. I want it to run in the standalone flash debugger without the Flash IDE!

This is driving me crazy. Please someone let me know how I change this. I'm on Mac if that makes a difference.

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed this was to go to my swf file that was published and make sure that the default 'open with' was set to Flash Player Debugger... NOT the flash IDE. Acutally I set all my swf files to open with Flash Debug player and it fixed the problem. Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I had already done what user334304 has suggested, but every time I deleted a file Flash Pro would open and alongside problems with FB4 using the non-debug Flash Player projector, this bugged the hell out of me until at 5am!

To simply stop Flash Pro opening every time a file is saved or deleted etc. you can disable the 'Build Automatically' option from the main 'Project' menu.

Otherwise, to stop Flash Pro opening completely you can:

1. Right-click on your project
2. Select 'Properties'
3. Select sub-category 'Builders'
4. Uncheck 'Flash Professional'

That should do the trick [note that you will need some other way to compile the fla/xfl file].

If anyone is interested (slightly off topic), to make FB4 open the correct Flash Player projector (debug player) it is best to:

1. Uninstall Flash Player with Adobe's util:
   **fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/uninstall_flash_player_osx.dmg** [Mac]
   **fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/uninstall_flash_player.exe** [Win]
2. Download the latest Flash Player Content Debuggers (plugin and projector) for your platform/browser from [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) (you can get the release version also)
3. Remove the Flash Players from Flash CS4, CS5 and FB4...

**CS4/CS5:** delete all content from

`[install directory]/Players/`

**FB4**: delete all content from

`[install directory]/player/`

Now unzip the downloaded Debugger, copy it into those directories and rename it to 'Flash Player.app' on Mac or 'Flash Player.exe' on Win.

And finally, from within the default OS environment change the default application that is used to launch .swf files to one of the debuggers that you just copied, ensuring that it is always used.

Restart Flash Builder and you should be good to go. No more time wasted when we'd rather be coding... thanks Adobe!

Answer (score 0):

Check what the default editor is for .swf files, go to your project Properties panel

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but the issue I believe the asker is referring to occurs when you have a project that is an "Flash Professional Project". Because the project is based on a Flash IDE *.fla file, it will always try to open Flash CS5.

I would recommend that you open/create your projects that don't rely on a *.fla file into FlashBuilder as an Actionscript Project. Import any assets you'll definitely need to compile by way of *.swc.

I definitely struggled with this problem too. Especially when my pipeline didn't yet include CS5 and it insisted on opening it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Flex or Actionscript project (in Flash Builder 4), and then run it, Flash Builder will launch a web browser with a generated HTML page containing your SWF.  It appears this is the default setting for Actionscript and Flex projects.

I've seen this work properly for a while, and at some point it will alter its behavior, so the SWF launches in Flash Pro.  The settings must have have been changed inadvertently sometime since the project was created.  I am researching how to set them back!

One workaround is to simply load the HTML page into your favorite browser and simply reload it every time you make changes to your code.  With auto-build on this should show you your changes.  Obviously this is not an ideal solution.